# How do I repair the "Fishscale" side of a cross country ski?

Tags: skiing, cross-country-skiing, repairs

I have a 20cm long, 2mm wide, 1mm deep gouge in the Fishscale portion of a cross country ski. How would I repair this scratch? Some have suggested Ptex will just burn into it too aggressively, others say that I would be best just getting a new ski. Any solutions/experience?

Comment: I had gouges in the bottom of my scales much bigger than that, just clean them up with a knife, and ride on. They're scales, no one wins any races riding scales, if you're going to buy new skis get some waxables.

Comment: Can you actually FEEL the difference between the skies?
As ShemSeger said, I have lots more gouges than that and it doesn't really degrade performance.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard that you can use Wax to at least "fill" the gouges. Won't be as good as new, but will be a bit better.
Remember, Nordic folks did just fine with no fishscales for, what? 100+ years?